# extending an AngularUI Bootstrap directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have some tabs in my application where I'm using some very similar markup.

```
<div data-tab>
  <div data-tab-heading>
    <i class="fa fa-bars visible-xs-inline"></i>
    <span class="hidden-xs">Text</span>
  </div>

  <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I pull this out into its own directive, do I need to use the compile option to avoid multiple templates (myTab, tab) on the root element?

```
function myTab() {
  return {
    compile: function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      // put the AngularUI tab directive on the root element here?
    },
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      faClass: '@',
      heading: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/layout/directives/tab.html',
    transclude: true
  };
}
```

tab.html:

```
<div>
  <div data-tab-heading>
    <i class="fa {{faClass}} visible-xs-inline"></i>
    <span class="hidden-xs">{{heading}}</span>
  </div>

  <div data-ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```